# Display Map on Custom Alert Dialog

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I am creating a custom alert dialog which displays a map inside of it. The map is created using the supportMapFragment (Code Below), is this a good practice or would you recommend a MapView instead?

Java class:

```
public class NearbyUtil implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static final String TAG = NearbyUtil.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context ctx;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    public NearbyUtil(Context context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        ctx = context;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        showDialog();
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.show();

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //... other code
}
```

XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `DialogFragment` then its better to use `MapView` otherwise you can use `supportMapFragment`.

An alternative process is to crate an `MapActivity` with `supportMapFragment` and add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your `MapActivity` in the `AndroidManifest`, it will show as a `dialog`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: thank you for your response! in regards to the MapActivity, if Have my mainActivity, would I jut initialize this as a regular activity? or since you mention it will show as a dialog how would I call it?

Comment: Yes its like normal activity. Using intent you can start this activity.

Comment: Thank you for your help this was very helpful!